# How do I give all users permissions to a SQL Server 2008 instance?

Tags: sql-server, installation

I have created an ini file that installs/creates a SQL Server instance.  I am able to connect and modify the databases attached to this instance fine.  However, if anyone else logs onto the machine, they can start the service fine but then get errors when trying to open connections.  What I need is for all users that log into the machine to have all permissions on the SQL Server instance.  I have seleced "Windows authentication mode" when building the install.  What setting am I forgetting that will give everyone the correct permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a login to cover all users:

```
create login [BUILTIN\Users] from windows;
```

Grant this login the priviledges needed by everyone.

Comment: Setting SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\Users" in my SQL install ini file got it working for all admin users.  But, we're doing final testing now and it's not allowing non-admin windows users to attach to the databases.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use Everyone you should use:

```
CREATE LOGIN [\Everyone] FROM WINDOWS;
```

If your OS version is non English you can find this name with:

```
SELECT SUSER_SNAME(SID_BINARY(N'S-1-1-0'));
```

Or combine it with:

```
DECLARE @Username nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @SqlStmt varchar(200)
SET @Username = SUSER_SNAME(SID_BINARY(N'S-1-1-0'))
SET @SqlStmt='CREATE LOGIN [' + @Username + '] FROM WINDOWS'

PRINT @sqlstmt
EXEC(@SqlStmt)
```